# How do I only change end date in v-date-picker range

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, date-range

I want to use v-date-picker to make a date range, Now when I first click a date, it is start Date, second click is end date. but I don't want to change start date, only change end date.

```
<v-date-picker v-model="timeRange" range no-title scrollable>
     <v-spacer></v-spacer>
     <v-btn text color="primary" @click="menu = false">
      Cancel
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn text color="primary" @click="$refs.menu.save(timeRange)">
      OK
       </v-btn>
</v-date-picker>


data(){
timeRange:["2022-04-10","2022-04-29"]
}
```

I don't want change "2022-04-10", just change "2022-04-29",
How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

What I came up with is a bit hacky but it seems to work:

First disallow the selection of any date earlier than your start date with the `allowed-dates` prop:

```html
<v-date-picker 
  v-model="timeRange" 
  range 
  no-title 
  scrollable
  :allowed-dates="(d) => new Date(d) >= new Date(timeRange[0])"
>
```

Then add a watcher for changes on your `timeRange` variable:

```js
watch: {
  timeRange(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue.length == 1) {
      this.timeRange = [oldValue[0], newValue[0]]
    }
  },
},
```

This code checks if the length of the new value is 1, which indicates that a start date has been chosen. We then construct a new array with the orignal start date and the clicked value as the new end date. That way the start date is fixed and cannot be changed.